# How to post form data to another page?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, curl, gravity-forms-plugin

IMPORTANT EDIT: I have edited my question to be more specific now.

what I want to do, is when user submits my gravity form, the data is sent to another wordpress platform where is also a form with the same fields. The data should be entered and submitted automatically and user should be redirected to Thank you page. I have read about cURL and GF Web API, but I haven't got them to work. I have made gform_after_submission HOOK where I have this code

```
add_action("gform_after_submission_7", "after_submission");
function after_submission($entry, $form){
//All the code that processes your form goes here 
$curl_handle = curl_init();
$body = array(
    'info' => rgar ( $entry, '5' ), 
    'name' => rgar ( $entry, '25' ), 
    'email' => rgar ( $entry, '2' ),
    'submit' => 'true',
    );
$data ='"info='.$body['info'].'&nimi='.$body["nimi"].'&email='.$body["email"].'"'; 

$url = "http://www.monica.ee/reisile/dev/kontakt";

curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );  //so we can post to https  

$result = curl_exec ($curl_handle);

curl_close ($curl_handle); 
//then once you have processed the form you can redirect to a success page
}
```

The page, where it should POST form data has these lines

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        if ($("#input_9_1").length) {
            console.log("<?php echo $_GET['nimi']; ?>");
        $('#input_9_1').val("<?php echo $_POST['info']; ?>");
        $('#input_9_2').val("<?php echo $_GET['nimi']; ?>");
        $('#input_9_3').val("<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>");
        //$('#input_9_4').val(<?php echo $_POST["mobiil"]; ?>);
        }
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            echo "$('#gform_submit_button_9').click();";
        }
        ?>
});
```

But right now when user submits my form, he is automatically redirected to thank you page and it doesn't seem to POST and submit this other form, where I am trying to send my data.

Can someone help me with this, I have been trying to solve this for the entire day now and it still won't work. I might do this completely the wrong way, but maybe someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could include all your validation and form processing code at the top of the page containing your form. Then if the validation and processing is successful redirect the user to a success page. So your form might look like this...

```
<?php

//Check if the form has been submitted
if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
    //Validate form
    $validation = validate_form($_POST);

    //If validation is successful process Form
    if( $validation['success'] == true ) {
        process_form($_POST);
    }

    //If validation has failed then output error message
    else {
        echo '<p class="error" id="validation-failed">' . $validation['error_message'] . '</p>';
    }
}

?>

<form id="kontaktvorm" method="post" action="">
    <div class="tekstikast">
        <textarea class="kontaktivorm medium" tabindex="1" rows="10" cols="50" tabindex="1" name="info">Sinu sõnum ...</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="nimekast">
        <input class="kontaktivorm poolikkast" type="text" tabindex="2" value="Nimi" name="nimi" />
    </div>
    <div class="epostikast">
        <input class="kontaktivorm poolikkast" tabindex="3" type="text" value="E-post" name="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="nupukast">
        <input type="submit" class="gform_image_button" tabindex="5" name="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

And then in your functions file you can include the two functions that validate and process your form...

```
/**
 * validates your form
 * @param  array $data the post data from the page
 * @return array
 */
function validate_form( $data ) {
    //Build our output array
    $output = array(
        'success' => true,
        'error_message' => null
    );

    //validate your fields... for example
    if( !$data['email'] || !is_email($data['email']) ) {
        $output['success'] = false;
        $output['error_message'] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }

    return $output;

} 

/**
 * processes your form data
 * @param  array $data the post data from the page
 */
function process_form($data) {
    //All the code that processes your form goes here 
    //then once you have processed the form you can redirect to a success page
    wp_redirect( home_url() . '/success' );
}
```

Hope that helps

Dan

Comment: So I should put my cURL code into this process_form function?

Comment: Yes, if you want to send the data to an external site then you should put it in the process form function however you should know that Wordpress has  helper functions for curl so you don't have to do it the long winded way. check out http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API

Comment: Do you know, why my submit button doesn't do anything?

Comment: I have updated my code to leave the form action empty so that it posts to the same page. try that. if it still doesn't do anything then could you check in developer tools and include the outputted code of your form in your question?

Comment: Still not working, Nothing happens, when I click the button. Edited question

Comment: @danbrahimi But do you know, if the cURL is correct? If this is correct, then is the code correct that I have for my landing page, where all data should be sent and automatically submitted?